# Split path by keyword with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Is there any way to split the path by specific keywords with htaccess?

For instance, if I have the paths:

```
example.com/dir1/dir2/etc/hello/var1/var2/var3/
example.com/goodbye/var1/var2/var3/
```

I would like to split at "hello" or "goodbye", like so:

```
example.com/dir1/dir2/etc/hello/?dirs=var1/var2/var3/
example.com/goodbye/?dirs=var1/var2/var3/
```

I don't know how many directories before "hello" or "goodbye", nor how many after that.

Can this be achieved only by parsing the URL afterwards (like with Node or PHP)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*(?:hello|goodbye)/)(.+)$    $1?dirs=$2  [NC,QSA,L]
```